# boost ptr_map replacing the value

Tags: c++, boost

Given a key, I am trying to replace a value.  With regular maps, that do not use pointers, I simply used the following call

```
iter->second = object; //Where object was passed in by reference
```

How do I achieve the same with boost::ptr_map?  The concept here is that we replace the entire class using the derived_object

```
iter->second = derived_object; //derived_object is a base_object pointer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
the_map.replace(iter, derived_object);
```

Where, of course, `the_map` is the map into which `iter` points.

Note that `ptr_map<K,V>::replace` returns a `ptr_map<K,V>::auto_type`, so you can grab the replaced object if you want. Of course, if you ignore it, it's automagically destroyed and you need never know it was there.