# insert or update in ptr_map

Tags: c++, boost

The insert method of ptr_map does not update data if a key exists. So we need to use replace:

[boost ptr_map replacing the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512642/boost-ptr-map-replacing-the-value)

Does ptr_map have a way of insertOrUpdate?

```
1) if a key does not exist, calls insert
2) if it exists, call replace
```

I guess this is how std::map insert works.

ptr_map has a [] operator. But it returns reference? I am not sure if it is safe to use it for doing the above.

Thank you,

Comment: if `ptr_map` is anything like `std::map`, then `operator[]` does exactly what you want. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128296/ptr-map-and-pointer

Comment: @vu1p3n0x it is, but it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess this is how std::map insert works

No. In fact, `std::map::insert` looks up a matching key and returns the iterator to the existing element, if found. It does **not** replace. (You maybe confused with `operator[]` which returns a lvalue reference to a new/existing element).

> ptr_map has a [] operator. But it returns reference? I am not sure if it is safe to use it for doing the above.

Of course you can. However, you should **not** assign to the reference if your element type is polymorphic. (Arguably, polymorphic value types are a key use case for Boost Pointer Containers). Because if you do you might end up with *Object Slicing* ([What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)).

If you truly want to replace the object (managed pointer) with /another object/ use `ptr_map::replace`. If you need to just update the object that is already in the map, feel free to use `operator[]`.

Comment: @hehe: I found insert releases data when it fails. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48121671/how-to-provent-ptr-map-releasing-data-when-it-fails-inserting, Is this expected?